# Dose Plastic SCM Support VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, plasticscm

Is any one having information that plastic SCM latest version supporting the vs 2015 integration. Went to there forum not getting exact picture that its supporting or not.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, supported since 5.4.16.674 back in June 2015 https://www.plasticscm.com/download/releasenotes/5.4.16.674

You can also see it in action in the gallery https://www.plasticscm.com/gallery.html